# redactedText in Dialogflow CX Webhook Requests

Tags: go, google-api, dialogflow-cx

I'm getting the following error when I'm using Dialogflow CX Webhook

> ```
> {"error":"unknown field \"redactedText\" in google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.ResponseMessage.Text"}
> ```

I'm using the code below to read the Webhook Request

```
wr := cx.WebhookRequest{}
if err = jsonpb.Unmarshal(r.Body, &wr); err != nil {
    //I have an error return function here, which returns the error above
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing the redactedText, and I can't find any documentation about it. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: does `jsonpb` **require** document to be strict to schema?

Answer (score 0):

Alecz,

It does look like `text` is returning an object instead of simply a string. To properly unmarshal the CX proto WebhookResponse, I'd recommend using the [protojson](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson) (as the jsonpb package has been deprecated), and configuring the [UnmarshalOptions](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson#UnmarshalOptions) like this:

```
err = protojson.UnmarshalOptions(protojson.UnmarshalOptions{
        AllowPartial:   true,
        DiscardUnknown: true,
    }).Unmarshal(r.Body, &wr)
```

My assumption is that it has to do with the [parameter redaction](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#redact) feature that CX has, but may not yet made it to the documentation.

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This worked well for now. Hopefully in the near future CX will update their documentation regarding redaction.